# Webpack - Requiring a file based on build configuration

Tags: webpack

In our project, it is possible to run the application in either **fake-backend** mode or **real-backend** mode. The idea is that the developer can develop locally with functions that implement backend API but return mock data.

I'd like to be able to do something like:

`webpack --config webpack-config-fake.js`

Then in the code I would to do something like that:

```
var mockSuffix = webpackConfig.options.isFake ? "-fake" : "";
var backendApi = require('backend-api'+mockSuffix+'.js')
```

Questions:

- Does that sound like the right way to do that?
- How can I access the used webpackConfig in my source?
- Another way I am considering is to use Webpack context. However, I am not sure if it could be used to help here. Is that something to consider?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your "fake" config, you could replace required modules via [`NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#normalmodulereplacementplugin). In the following example, `require('backend-api')` yields `backend-api-mock`.

```js
plugins: [
  new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/backend-api/, function(result) {
    result.request = result.request.replace(/(backend-api)/, '$1-mock');
  }),
],
```

You could also indicate that your mock folder takes precedence when resolving requests. See [`resolve.root`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root). In the following example, `require('backend-api')` will first look into `mockPath` and fall back to `dependenciesPath` if no corresponding module was found.

```js
resolve: {
  root: [mockPath, dependenciesPath],
},
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into that option.

Comment: This was awesome, thanks! I've been trying to use some external `string-replace` plugins for this and this one is out of the box!