# Webpack conditional build based on configuration values

Tags: javascript, requirejs, reactjs, webpack

I'm looking for what ultimately would be a Webpack equivalent to Require.JS's **has.js** integration.

In Require.JS you can compile different code paths based on a variable in has.js. Is there an equivalent loader/plugin for Webpack to do the same thing?

Example:

**config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  option1: 'foo' // other option is 'bar'
}
```

then in code somewhere have something like the following

**code.js**

```
var a;

if (option1 === 'foo') {
  a = require('fooModule');
} else if (option1 === 'bar') {
  a = require('barModule');
}
```

and have a build only output the code in the condition that evaluates as true?

Alternatively, something like this would work, as well:

```
import MyLibrary from './modules/' + config.option1 + 'Module.js';
```

would [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491622/webpack-requiring-a-file-based-on-build-configuration) be the current best practice to achieve what i'm looking for? ultimately, the goal is to have a single set of source that can compile down to specific(ish) targets based on values in a configuration, while not sending non-applicable code down the wire as well in the final build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the webpack [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to do this. Pete Hunt's [Webpack Howto](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto#6-feature-flags) has a good example of implementation.

Comment: accepting over my own answer (which *was* first ;) ) b/c of the link. helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the best, most *webpack idiomatic* way to handle this is through the

[Webpack DefinePlugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin)

Answer (score -1):

The [webpack-hasjs-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-hasjs-plugin/) should do what you want.